# CSS setting background image with data attribute

Tags: html, css

This has probably been asked before, but is it possible to set the background image with css based on the data attribute?

I have this:

```
<div class="imageWrap" data-bigImage="someURl" data-smallImage="someUrl"></div>
```

and my CSS:

```
background-image: attr(data-bigImage url);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

I use these 2 sizes for an responsive solution, and the data attribute can be changed by an admin, so I cannot set a path to a specific file..

How can I solve this? Is there a non-javascript solution?

Comment: [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) only works (reliably) in conjunction with [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) which itself is only applicable to pseudo-elements. Without the aid of Javascript the answer to your question would be "no, it's not possible."

Comment: @AndréDion is correct. But you could use this behaviour to your advantage, and let the "big image" be displayed inside a pseduo element,  like `.imageWrap:hover::after{ content: attr(data-bigImage);  }`

Comment: Could you not use sprites and then just adjust size & position depending on screen/viewport size? That way the image URL can remain same and there wouldn't be much need for JS too. (Just thinking out loud and I've never tried it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done the way you want to.
What you could do is create two child div's, and toggle between them.

```
<div class="imageWrap">
   <div class="bigImage" style="background-image:url('someUrl');"></div>
   <div class="smallImage" style="background-image:url('someUrl');"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS would then look something like this:

```
.imageWrap .bigImage,
.imageWrap .smallImage{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
}
.imageWrap .smallImage{
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:sizeInPx){
    .imageWrap .smallImage{
       display:block;
    }
    .imageWrap .largeImage{
      display:none;
    }
}
```

I would however prefer a javascript solution, since that wouldn't require me to preload / buffer two images.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did! :-) Thanks anyway! :-)